# How do I compute a sample data set from my original data set?

Tags: r, plyr, sampling, tidy

See a snippet of the following data set:

```
    $ HOMEMTOT             : int  4278 2389 1264 3249 6048 1705 5304 11091 1289 13347 ...
 $ MULHERTOT            : int  4213 2298 1278 3170 5667 1541 4931 11388 1254 11777 ...
 $ pesoRUR              : int  4464 1649 1588 1369 9269 885 2886 12910 221 10895 ...
 $ pesotot              : int  8491 4687 2542 6419 11715 3246 10235 22479 2543 25124 ...
 $ pesourb              : int  4027 3038 954 5050 2446 2361 7349 9569 2322 14229 ...
 $ Estados              : Factor w/ 26 levels "AC","AL","AM",..: 2 10 22 25 10 25 12 6 17 12 ...
```

I am intending to conduct a PCA and LASSO regression, but the issue is that I am supposed to set aside a sample size of 10 municipalities, coined "Estados," as seen above. How would I say make a sample set of, say, 300 observations based on 10 random municipalities "Estados." ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(Estados %in% sample(Estados, 10, replace = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(Estados) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 30) %>%
  ungroup()
```